# Button Ajax script isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-conversion

My AJax script for my button which converts a file and stores it in a folder isnt working I don't get any files in the folder.

My view code

```
`@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
    int i = 1;
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<table style="background-color: lightgreen; border: solid 2px black;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Name</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Size</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Preview</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Read File</b>
        </td>
         <td>
            <b>Convert File</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var file in Model)
    {    
        <tr>
            <td>
                @file.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @(file.Size / 1000) KB
            </td>
            <td>
                @(file.extension)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="btnreadfile@(i)" name="@file.Name" class='btnClick' type="button" value="Read File"/>
                <textarea  rows="4" cols="50" class="txtArea@(i)" name ="txtArea">@(ViewBag.DataVal)
</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="btnconvertfile" name="@file.Name" class='btnClick2' type="button" value="Convert File"/>

            </td>
        </tr>   
        i++;
    }
</table>

<textarea></textarea>
<aside>
    <h3>Aside Title</h3>
    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</aside>

<script>
    $(".btnClick").click(function () {
        var selectedId = $(this).attr("id").replace("btnreadfile", "");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ReadTextFile",
            type: "GET",
            data: { fileName: $(this).attr("name") },
            DataType: "text",
            success: function (str) {
                $(".txtArea" + selectedId).val(str);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(".btnClick2").click(function () {
        var selectedId = $(this).attr("id").replace("btnConvertfile", "");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Shared/About",
            type: "POST",
            data: {document: $(this).attr ("name")},
            DataType: "pdf",
            success: function (str) {
                $("~/downloads/" + selectedId).val(str);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
</script>`
```

My method code

```
   `public ActionResult About() 
            Document document = new Document();
            try
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/") + "downloads/" + "print.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                document.Open();
                //string body = TextArea1.value;
                List<IElement> htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
                                  new StringReader(Request["txtArea"]), null);
                for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
                {
                    document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
                }

                Paragraph mypara = new Paragraph();
                document.Add(mypara);

                document.Close();

               return Redirect("~/downloads/print.pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.DataVal = ex.Message;
                return View();
            }

        }
    }
}`
```

The aim is to convert files from a textArea into a pdf file by clicking the button. How would I write the script? I think I've done it wrong.

Comment: Why are using btnClick class name in both the script ?

Comment: Your AJAX Url points to a different Action than you are showing? I.e. **AJAX** = `/Home/ReadTextFile` but your **Action** = `About()`? Can you show actual code?

Comment: About is shared the /Home/ReadTexFile is for a different button which works fine the button i'm focusing on is the convert button

Comment: You're doing Convert in the About ? Which controller is that in ? (The About I mean)